# Add Image uploader in Product page for Customers images to product

Tags: php, magento

Actually i have given with the task that I want to provide image uploading option in front end at product page for registered customers to add their own image for the products and should be visible only to them. But this should done with touching the core part in magento. I didn't even get the idea how to do.. Anybody please help. Thank you in advance..

Comment: You can try with custom options

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following steps:
1. add a product's custom file attribute (**Is Required** should be **No**)
2. add a class for identifying **file** type option on **dl** under **product-options** div at the front end view.you can use jQuery for this purpose and do not forget to include jQuery.
3. you need to check the logged in customer (view.pthml). try the codes below

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery(".product-options dl dt").each(function(){
          if(jQuery(this).next().find("input").attr("type") == 'file'){
            jQuery(this).next().addClass('file-field');
          }
        });
    }); 
</script>
<?php if (Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()) : ?> 
    <style>
        .file-field{visibility: visible;}
    </style>
<?php else: ?>
    <style>
        .file-field{visibility: hidden;}
    </style>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Great, this is working fine for logged in customers only. Thank you. But also i need that the image selected by custom option should be displayed in product page. this is the main. pls help me for this. should be shown permanently to that customer only and can be customize only by that customer and admin.

Comment: if you want to show the selected image on product page please check the link `http://jsfiddle.net/LvsYc/`. additionally if you want show uploaded images permanently for individual customer you need to pull all previous images from backend. that would be better if you make a image gallery for specific customer in front end.